# How do i get old modification values in Realm Javascript when that data has been changed

Tags: javascript, database, realm

**Hello Everyone!**

To retrieve data I use `Realm.objects(some_collection)` method, then I am adding `.addListener()` method to watch changes that data in real-time, but Realm give an unexpected result where the result from `.addListener()` method is just an `index` of the data that has been changed NOT the `value`

**Code**

```js
import Realm from 'realm';

const userdata = Realm.objects('user')[0]; // {name: 'Herry', age: 21}

/**
 * "collection" is "[object]" same as "userdata"
 * "changes" is an object
 */
userdata.addListener(function (collection, changes) {
  /**
   * All the result from "changes" param is just an "[index_the_data_that_has_been_changed]"
   *
   * If i want to get an old modification value with 
   * "collection[changes.oldModifications[0]]" it just resulting a new value
   * NOT the old value :(
   */
  console.log(changes.insertions)
  console.log(changes.modifications)
  console.log(changes.oldModifications)
  console.log(changes.newModifications)
  console.log(changes.deletions)
});
```

Any idea

Comment: have you try `.snapshot()` method?

Comment: yeah, but you can't use `.addListener()` method on it

Comment: and that's why they make `.snapshot()` method, IMO

Comment: in the Docs it say `Create a frozen snapshot of the collection.`

Comment: and from that way you can get an old value from it

Comment: @AngularSan Ahhh I see!!! I didn't think about it, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use .snapshot() method to get the old value

```
import Realm from 'realm';

/* Use "let" not "const" */
let userdata = Realm.objects('user').snapshot();

Realm.objects('user').addListener(function (collection, changes) {
  /* get old value */
  const oldVal = userdata[changes.oldModifications[the_index]];
  console.log(oldVal);

  /* If you done get old value from "userdata" call again */
  userdata = Realm.objects('user').snapshot();
});
```

Comment: I think you're wrong about `.snapshot()` also in the Docs they say `This is not a deep snapshot. Realm objects contained in this snapshot will continue to update as changes are made to them, and if they are deleted from the Realm they will be replaced by null at the respective indices.`

Comment: And I've been trying it and it still gets new value from that `.snapshot()`

Comment: Well, I was wrong sorry for that, and my solution is you have to destroy all methods, getters, etc. Because the result from `Realm.objects()` is a `Class` Instance, to do that destructing an `object` with spread operator like `...object` it will be destroying the `Class` and resulting just a plain `object` OR you can use `JSON.stringify()` for destroying the `Class` too, and when I see at Docs they have `.toJSON()` method for `freezing` the `collection`